# Custom fildes for Rainlab.User

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

Octobercms Rainlab.Builder allows you to edit only certain fields. Can I add custom fields? For example, home address. 
If this can not be done, then tell me the plugin that allows you to do it. Or will you have to write code from scratch?
[Fields of User Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DauOL.png)

Comment: try this plugin : https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-userplus, it will add street_addr, city, zip. fields

Comment: Here is a youtube series that specifically talks about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AomK1eYAq78&list=PLUBR53Dw-Ef-X-_A1KLy41r2QArCBy4rM&index=23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no visual tool to add fields to the user plugin.

However as Hardik Satasiya suggested you could use: [User Plus+](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-userplus)

Another way would be to use the Builder plugin to setup a basic plugin.
This new plugin you wil have to modify a little bit.
For that i suggest looking at:

- https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#usage-examples
- https://github.com/rainlab/userplus-plugin

To add the new fields to the existing `user` table have a look at the second link in the list above.
Under the folder: `/updates/user_add_profile_fields.php`